# Cant run react-native app after 'npm run eject' on expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I created a react project by executing the command

> expo init

(created a blank project)
I ran this on an android emulator (works good)

I want to get out from expo as I have some custom code.
so I executed

> npm run eject

it went well, then I executed

> react-native run-android

to open the app on an android emulator

I am getting the following error

> PS C:\mobileApp\one> react-native run-android
>   C:\mobileApp\one\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:128
>   function getCliConfig(){var cliArgs,config,expoAssetPluginPath;return
>   regeneratorRuntime.async(function
>   getCliConfig$(_context){while(1){switch(_context.prev=_context.next){case
>   0: ^
>
> ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined at getCliConfig
>   (C:\mobileApp\one\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:128:64)
>   at Object.
>   (C:\mobileApp\one\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\core\index.js:181:30)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30) at
>   Module._compile
>   (C:\mobileApp\one\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24) at
>   Module._extensions…js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10) at
>   Object.newLoader [as .js]
>   (C:\mobileApp\one\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7) at
>   Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32) at tryModuleLoad
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12) at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3) at Module.require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17) PS C:\mobileApp\one>

please help

Comment: Have you tried restarting metro bundler?

Comment: Having the same issue with a brand new expo init project like the documentation suggests. Have you figured out how to fix this? doesn't seem the latest version work correctly. i think i will try a previous version.

Comment: I couldn't fix it, started to use react-native-cli (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed node_modules, edited `package.json` and `.babelrc` like this. It worked after reinstall of npm modules.

`{
  "name": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}`

babel.config.js needs to be replaced with .babelrc

`{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}`